# Как на другой форме определить, что пользователь авторизовала по паре логин-пароль на flask

Tags: python, flask

Есть тестовое приложение без базы данных. Информация хранится в словаре:

```
users = {'user1': 'password1', 'user2': 'password2'}
```

Приложение состоит из двух файлов (помимо файлов шаблонизатора). Одни файл отвечает за регистрацию, а второй за главную страницу. Файлы связаны друг с другом.
Код файла, отвечающего за регистрацию:

```
from flask import *


login_controller = Blueprint('login_controller', __name__)

# Пример "базы данных" пользователей
users = {'user1': 'password1', 'user2': 'password2'}

@login_controller.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        # Проверяем существование пользователя и правильность пароля
        if username in users and users[username] == password:
            # Устанавливаем имя пользователя в сессии при успешной аутентификации
            session['username'] = username
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')

@login_controller.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Удаляем имя пользователя из сессии при выходе
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Код файла, отвечающего за главную страницу:

```
from flask import *


from login_web_controller import get_username, login_controller

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.register_blueprint(login_controller)

#просто слова для вывода списком на главную страницу
users = ['first', 'second', 'third']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if session['username'] not in session:
        # Если информации о пользователе нет в сессии, делаем редирект на страницу авторизации
        return redirect(url_for('login_controller.login'))
    return render_template("index.html", users=users)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5012)
```

Проблема возникает в строчке:

```
if session['username'] not in session:
```

Так как регистрация происходи на форме логин, то просто положить информацию в переменную и сравнить по значению я не могу (да и не хотел бы такой колхоз разводить). Подскажите, чем необходимо воспользоваться, чтобы определить, что пользователь прошел регистрацию и может быть допущен до главной страницы и наоборот редиректить пользователей, которые еще не авторизовали

Comment: `if 'username' not in session:` — почти идентичный пример даже в [документации фласка](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#sessions) написан

Comment: @andreymal, здравствуйте, повторюсь, информация размещена в разных файлах, просто перенести информацию не получается, поэтому и ищу другие способы

Comment: А при чём тут какие-то файлы? Сессия хранится в браузерных куках

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то username - это просто строка, но ведь мне неизвестно имя пользователя, я его никуда не записываю, а если бы и записывал, то при переходе в другой файл это значение не сохранилось бы

Comment: Вы записали его в сессию в строке `session['username'] = username`, сессия хранится в куках, никакие файлы тут не нужны и не используются

Comment: Повторюсь. Сам мой проект разделен на два файла, для работы как контроллеры. Поэтому у меня изначально информация об авторизации не находится в том же файле, в котором идет проверка на наличие пользователя в сессии. Код на проверку наличия session['username'] в session всегда отвечает, что пользователя в сессии нет (хотя на точке остановы session['username'] показывает, что он не пустой и содержит то, что я положил при авторизации). Поэтому я либо ошибаюсь в условии с проверкой на наличие, либо сама подобная проверка делается иначе. Буду рад, если Вы посоветуете еще что-то

Comment: Проверять наличие session['username'] в session - это какой-то бред. Нужно проверять наличие 'username' в session. Ещё раз посмотрите самый первый комментарий и ещё раз посмотрите документацию Flask

Comment: Уважаемый сверху прав. session['username'] в session не проверяют, проверяю 'username'  в session. Даже если вы создаёте сессию в своём blueprint-е, сессия все равно хранится в куки, а куки в браузере пользователя, так что не важно, в blueprint-е вы авторизовываетесь или нет. Если объяснить для вашей логики: Куки созданные в blueprint сами уже передадутся в главный файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проверить, авторизован ли пользователь, то после заполнения формы авторизации, вы создаёте сессию.

```
session['username'] = username
```

После чего в маршруте логин добавляете условия проверки авторизованности

```
@login_controller.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if 'username' in session:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       username = request.form['username']
       password = request.form['password']

       # Проверяем существование пользователя и правильность пароля
       if username in users and users[username] == password:
        # Устанавливаем имя пользователя в сессии при успешной аутентификации
        session['username'] = username
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')
```